# Remove duplicates but keep some

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it possible to remove duplicates but keep last 3-4 ? Something like:

```
 df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID'], keep='last_four')
```

Thank you

Comment: IIUC you could do `df.groupby('ID').tail(4)` I think should work

Comment: I have a dataset where some ID are repeated but their other columns are not. I want to compare last 4 occurences of those IDs. @EdChum I'm testing your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) and pass the num of rows you wish to keep to achieve the same result:

```
In [5]:   
# data setup 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4], 'val':np.arange(25)})
df
Out[5]:
    ID  val
0    0    0
1    0    1
2    0    2
3    0    3
4    0    4
5    0    5
6    1    6
7    1    7
8    1    8
9    1    9
10   1   10
11   1   11
12   1   12
13   2   13
14   2   14
15   3   15
16   3   16
17   3   17
18   3   18
19   3   19
20   3   20
21   3   21
22   3   22
23   3   23
24   4   24
```

Now `groupby` and call `tail`:

```
In [11]:    
df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).tail(4)

Out[11]:
    ID  val
2    0    2
3    0    3
4    0    4
5    0    5
9    1    9
10   1   10
11   1   11
12   1   12
13   2   13
14   2   14
20   3   20
21   3   21
22   3   22
23   3   23
24   4   24
```